# Can't use postgres function of a certain scope

Tags: postgresql

I have a script that tries to use the function

```
public.gen_random_uuid()
```

but postgres returns: `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

But when I try just `SELECT gen_random_uuid();` it works fine. So clearly
the public. is breaking it.

I tried removing the `public` from my search_path but that doesn't help either.

Any ideas?

Comment: "*So clearly the public*" - not all. What does `show search_path` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably it's in a different schema. Check. In `psql`:

```
\df gen_random_uuid
```

will show you the schema.

Otherwise:

```
select p.proname, n.nspname
from pg_proc p inner join pg_namespace n on (p.pronamespace = n.oid)
where p.proname = 'gen_random_uuid';
```